# How to exclude a css file from a requireJS build?

Tags: wordpress, requirejs

I am using requireJS to minify js and css files for a wordpress theme, however I want the style.css to be ignored when requireJS builds the optimized theme as the optimized theme folder is supposed to have another style.css file.

My app.build.js file looks like this:

```
({
appDir: "../",
baseUrl: "js",
dir: "../../target/",
modules: [
    {
        name: "main"
    }
],
paths: {
    [...]
},
shim: {
    [...]
}
})
```

I have previously tried to add the following to no avail:

```
fileExclusionRegExp: /^style$/,
```

Answer (score 0):

Since knowing when the file has loaded is not reliable, it does not make sense to explicitly support CSS files in RequireJS loading, since it will lead to bug reports due to browser behavior.

That's why Requirejs does not support CSS loading.

Comment: But requireJS does optimize css files? What you're saying is that excluding style.js from the build would work, but not style.css?
With the build, I am thinking of when requireJS is run using:

node ../r.js -o app.build.js

Everything is copied over and optimized in /target/, but I'd like to exclude style.css from that process.